# Moving files with dropzone working on localhost but showing 500 internal server error on ubuntu server

Tags: laravel, file-upload, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I have implemented dropzone drag and drop for upload image with Laravel which working fine in my localhost. But when I uploaded it to my ubuntu server it's not uploading images but showing 500 internal server error in browser console.

Here is my view file code...

```
{!! Form::open([ 'route' => [ 'dropzone.store' ], 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'image-upload' ]) !!}
<div>
<h5 style="text-align: center;">Drag and Drop or Click to Upload Product Images</h5>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Here is the javascript...

```
var jsarray = [];
        Dropzone.options.imageUpload = {
            maxFilesize         :       8,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",

            success: function(file, response){
                console.log(response.success);
            }

        };
```

Route:

```
Route::get('dropzone', 'ImageController@dropzone');
Route::post('dropzone/store',['as'=>'dropzone.store','uses'=>'ImageController@dropzoneStore']);
```

Controller:

```
public function dropzoneStore(Request $request)
    {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $imageName = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = "images";
        $image->move($path,$imageName);
        return response()->json(['success'=>$imageName]);
    }
```

Error in browser console:

```
POST http://finance.technozone.com.au/finance/dropzone/store 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Please anybody help me to solve my problem.....

Comment: It could be folder permission issue. Is the folder you are trying to save the image writable?

Comment: Yes. Folder permission set to 755

Comment: You can probably find the real error (that is causing the 500 Internal Server Error) in your log files in storage/logs.

Comment: [2017-03-26 14:09:00] local.ERROR: ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/finance/Laravel/storage/framework/sessions/g63tWR0dzhqE0UNliHH5zUDBFQpOTGiCj0JGldKw): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/finance/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:111

Comment: This is the error in the laravel.log file

Comment: In local, where your images get actually stored?

Comment: I have solved this problem. There was a folder permission error in another folder. Thanks for your supporting.